# oracle sum over() with where clause

Tags: oracle, grouping

[image]
that's how it should look like.

another special question. i have the following data and query:

```
with helptab as (  
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual    
union all  
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual    
union all    
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all    
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6762' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6763' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6835' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6835' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 1 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6835' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 1 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6835' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '6835' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 1 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 1 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8904' as nr, 'D' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 1 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'B' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'C' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual    
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'A' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual  
union all  
select '8905' as nr, 'D' as sub_val, 0 as sub_nr from dual)  
select nr, sub_val, sub_nr, count(sub_val) as cnt
, case when sub_val = 'A' then 0 when sum(count(sub_val)) over(partition by nr) >= 5 then count(sub_val) else 0 end as MoreThan5
, case when sub_val = 'A' then count(sub_val) when sum(count(sub_val)) over(partition by nr) < 5 then count(sub_val) else 0 end as LessThan5
from helptab 
group by nr, sub_val, sub_nr
order by nr, sub_val, sub_nr
```

how it should work:
every Row where sub_val equals 'A' must has result on the LessThan5 column. all others need to be checked by sum over nr and Sub_val (except 'A'). when less then 5, all results have to be placed on LessThan5 column too,  otherwise on MoreThan5. i thought sum() over(Partition by) is the right way, but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Two simple tables in the question -- with sample data and desired results -- would really help others understand what you want to do.

Comment: i just added a pic to (hopefully) make it clearer

Comment: Please make sure you read the guidelines for posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly, two small modifications are needed:

```
select nr, sub_val, sub_nr, count(sub_val) as cnt,
       case 
         when sub_val = 'A' then 0
         when sum(count(case when sub_val <> 'A' then sub_val end))  -- <-- here
              over(partition by nr) >= 5 then count(sub_val)
         else 0
       end as MoreThan5,
       case
         when sub_val = 'A' then count(sub_val)
         when sum(count(case when sub_val <> 'A' then sub_val end))  -- <-- and here
              over(partition by nr) < 5 then count(sub_val)
         else 0
       end as LessThan5
  from helptab
 group by nr, sub_val, sub_nr
 order by nr, sub_val, sub_nr
```

Comment: You are welcome. I think you can change `sum(count(...))` to simple `count(...)`, but please check it.

Comment: I am surprised that this query does anything useful.  Using a `group by` column as the condition for conditional aggregation seems unusual.